# Better way to load a XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am reading a XMl and using it for some processing in my application.

```
var config =  XElement.Load("c:/sample.xml");
```

Is there anyway to do load it in a better way? it takes a while while trying to process this line of code.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: “using it for some processing”? Like what, exactly?

Comment: Look into deserializing into a strongly typed object. 

[Xml Deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, it provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data.

Answer (score 1):

You use so call DOM model of loading document which loads the whole XML. An alternative is a SAX model when you read data in consecutive manner. The API for that is [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: There is a Java article but it will give you an idea of what's going on http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch09s11.html